# C# Get value from dropdown

Tags: javascript, html, drop-down-menu

I am trying to get the value of the selected possibility in the dropdown menu. If "Production" is selected I want to get the value = "prod". But i won't work.

```
 <div class="btn dropdown-toggle col-sm-2" type="button" id="menu1" data- 
toggle="dropdown" style="font-size: 10px;">
                            Alle
<span class="caret" style="text-align:center"></span>
       </div>
<ul class="dropdown-menu" role="menu" aria-labelledby="menu1">
<li role="presentation"><a value="all" role="menuitem" tabindex="-1" 
href="#">All</a></li>
<li role="presentation"><a value="prod" role="menuitem" tabindex="-1" 
href="#">Production</a></li>
<li role="presentation"><a value="hour" role="menuitem" tabindex="-1" 
href="#">Hour</a></li>
<li role="presentation"><a value="adhoc" role="menuitem" tabindex="-1" 
href="#">Adhoc</a></li>
                        </ul>
```

I have been trying to use:  var e = document.getElementById("menu1"); ,but I am only able to get the innerText ="Production" with  var type = e.innerText.toString();, but not able to get the value....

I know there exist a similar question like this one: [Get value from Dropdown](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/51963392/get-value-from-dropdown), but the answer does not work in my case. Any suggestions ?

Comment: Do you use any framework component or 3rd party implementation of a drop down ? (you should as i can see) . and what is that ?

Comment: I am using Bootstrap 3....

Comment: how this is related to c#?

Answer (score 0):

Get the inner text and find the `a` element with that, then you can get the value

```
var e = document.getElementById("menu1");
var element = $( "#menu1 a:contains('"+ e.innerText.toString() +"')" );
var value = element.attr('value');
```

P.S: I created a demo of a working Bootstrap 3 drop down implementation. you can see when changing the drop down value it prints the value attribute

```js
$('.dropdown-menu').on( 'click', 'a', function() {
    var text = $(this).html();
    console.log('Value changed to ', $(this).attr('value'));
    var htmlText = text + ' <span class="caret"></span>';
    $(this).closest('.dropdown').find('.dropdown-toggle').html(htmlText);
});
```

```html
                        
                        <div class="dropdown">
  <button class="btn btn-default dropdown-toggle" type="button" id="menu1" data-toggle="dropdown" aria-haspopup="true" aria-expanded="true">
    Dropdown
    <span class="caret"></span>
  </button>
<ul class="dropdown-menu" role="menu" aria-labelledby="menu1">
  <li role="presentation"><a value="all" role="menuitem" tabindex="-1" 
  href="#">All</a></li>
  <li role="presentation"><a value="prod" role="menuitem" tabindex="-1" 
  href="#">Production</a></li>
  <li role="presentation"><a value="hour" role="menuitem" tabindex="-1" 
  href="#">Hour</a></li>
  <li role="presentation"><a value="adhoc" role="menuitem" tabindex="-1" 
  href="#">Adhoc</a></li>
</ul>
</div>


<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<script src="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.3.7/js/bootstrap.min.js"></script>
<link href="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.3.7/css/bootstrap.min.css" rel="stylesheet"/>
```